# very strange results of numpy.astype with numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

WHY? very strange...
In python, if we test np.astype() with `numba`, the following will print some results as

```
x:     [-6. -5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
x-int: [-6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5]

@numba.njit
def tt():
    nn = 3
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*nn-1, 4*nn)-2*nn
    print(x)
    print(x.astype(np.int32))
```

BUT, if I change the line of x to be `x = np.linspace(0, 8*nn-1, 8*nn)-4*nn`, the result will be strange as

```
x: [-12. -11. -10.  -9.  -8.  -7.  -6.  -5.  -4.  -3.  -2.  -1.   0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.]
x-int: [-12 -11 -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   0   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11]
```

There are two `0` in x-int? why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** This is a reported bug of Numba.

The issue come from a slightly inaccuracy in the Numba `linspace` function related to floating-point rounding. Here is an example to highlight the issue:

```py
def tt_classic():
    nn = 3
    return np.linspace(0, 8*nn-1, 8*nn)-4*nn

@numba.njit
def tt_numba():
    nn = 3
    return np.linspace(0, 8*nn-1, 8*nn)-4*nn

print(tt_classic()[13])
print(tt_numba()[13])
```

Here is the result:

```
1.0
0.9999999999999982
```

As you can see, the Numba implementation does not return a exact value. While this problem cannot be avoided for big values, it can be considered as a **bug** for such small value since they can be *represented exactly* (without any loss of precision) on any IEEE-754 platform.

As a result, the cast will then truncate the floating point number 0.9999999999999982 to 0 (and *not to the nearest integer*). If you want a *safe conversion* (ie. workaround), you can explicitly tell Numpy/Numba to do it. Here is an example:

```
@numba.njit
def tt():
    nn = 3
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*nn-1, 4*nn)-2*nn
    np.round(x, 0, x)
    print(x)
    print(x.astype(np.int32))
```

This bug as been reported on the Numba bug tracker [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6526).
You may also be interested in [this](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2648) related Numba issue.